# How to change the GDM default background wallpaper to my customized wallpaper or solid color?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, gdm

I was trying to change the Ubuntu 11.04 GDM default background wallpaper to solid color such as black. However it's not working; here is what I've tried so far:

1. From the terminal:

   ```
   xsetroot -bg black -solid black
   ```
2. From /etc/gdm/custom.conf:

   ```
   [greeter]
   BackgroundImage=/var/tmp/x1.png
   BackgroundColor=#000000
   BackgroundType=2
   ```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two questions, does making the file you reference here:
BackgroundImage=/var/tmp/x1.png
specifically x1.png a black square, or transparent, fix it?

Second have you tried:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIaUvfuNY-E